# Why my liquibase modifySQL clause is not triggered?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, yaml, liquibase, jsonb

I'm trying to define my DBMS schema with [liquibase](/questions/tagged/liquibase) (in a [spring-boot](/questions/tagged/spring-boot) project). The relevant part of this project is the JSON storage I'm trying to setup.

Even I know that most relational DBMS are not able to process JSON correctly or are just starting to (as for may 2016), I want to have a kind of vendor agnostic schema.
So, I set blob (or anything else, advise would be appreciate) as default datatype for any RDBMS, and I specialized it for those able to deal with : the famous JSONB for [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql), or a least JSON for [h2](/questions/tagged/h2) and [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql).

As I use [spring-boot](/questions/tagged/spring-boot), I don't have so much config (indeed none ;))

It seems that the modifySQL clause is not triggerred. I'm using the following changeset.

#### YAML Liquibase Changeset

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: 1
      author: jrevy
      changes:
        - createTable:
            tableName: recipe
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: id
                  type: uuid
                  constraints:
                    primaryKey: true
                    nullable: false
              - column:
                  name: name
                  type: varchar(255)
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
              - column:
                  name: data
                  type: blob
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
      modifySql:
        - replace:
            dbms: postgresql
            replace: blob
            with: jsonb
        - replace:
            dbms: h2,mysql
            replace: blob
            with: json
```

### Result

```
INFO 24/05/16 14:56: liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
INFO 24/05/16 14:56: liquibase: Creating database history table with name: public.databasechangelog
INFO 24/05/16 14:56: liquibase: Reading from public.databasechangelog
INFO 24/05/16 14:56: liquibase: classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml: classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml::1::jrevy: Table recipe created
INFO 24/05/16 14:56: liquibase: classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml: classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml::1::jrevy: ChangeSet classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml::1::jrevy ran successfully in 46ms
INFO 24/05/16 14:56: liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
[...]
INFO 67628 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final}
2016-05-24 14:56:33.765  INFO 67628 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2016-05-24 14:56:33.765  INFO 67628 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2016-05-24 14:56:34.030  INFO 67628 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2016-05-24 14:56:34.280  INFO 67628 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
```

-->

```
-- Column: data

-- ALTER TABLE recipe DROP COLUMN data;

ALTER TABLE recipe  ADD COLUMN data bytea;
ALTER TABLE recipe ALTER COLUMN data SET NOT NULL;
```

Datatype should be [jsonb](/questions/tagged/jsonb), not bytea (it works quite well if I use jsbon as default data type, but only for pgSQL).

### Question

- How can I know if modifySQL clause is detected / triggered ?
- Do you know why it's not working as expected ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove - before **replace** (https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/e0badd697d82a87ba868b41e68b659cf8c8e68e8/liquibase-integration-tests/src/test/resources/changelogs/yaml/rollback.tests.changelog.yaml) ?

Try modifySql without dbms to see if it is triggered. And test with liquibase cmd line to exclude spring-boot bug.